# VBA - For Each Row - compare for duplicates based on certain column

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I hope I am not asking too much by asking for an explanation with an answer.

I want to look for duplicates in my activeworksheet based on 3 different columns per rows. Then I want to highlight that EntireRow (used cells only) any color.

I need to store 3 different cells in the first row then loop through each used row and compare it to the 3 next relative cells

So far I have gutted some other peoples nice code for the loop but i dont know how to properly do what i want.

```
Sub CompareHighlightDupRows()
Dim oRow As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRows As Range
With Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set myRows = Intersect(.Range("A:A").EntireRow, .UsedRange)
    If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End With
For Each oRow In myRows.Columns(1).Cells

Next


End Sub
```

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer myself using a simpler method
    Do While RowCount <> lastROW + 1

```
Do While RowCount <> lastROW + 1

RowCount = RowCount + 1
Loop

RowCount = RowCount + 1
Loop
```

going to use cells(rowcounter,columncounter) with a string concatenation to compare and an entirerow.usedrange to highlight interior color